# How to use different buttons on a view?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view to create new customer and update customer. But I want to display 1 of 2 buttons when required. For example, when I want to create a new customer, the button is create, and when I want to update, the button is update. I'm a newbie, so can you specify what to do to help me? Thanks a lot !!

when i click to this link update below, it will return this view with button is update

```html
   <a href="{{url('customer/'.$customer->id)}}" name="update" > Update </a>
```

Below is function of route CustomersController after click to link above

```php
    class CustomersController extends Controller
    {
        function editCus($id)
        {
            $chanels  = Group::childs('khachhang');
            $customer = Customers::find($id);
            $cities     = City::where('country','VN')->get();
            return view('sale.customer', compact('chanels','customer','cities'));
        }
    }
```

View sale.customer

```html
    <form class="form form-horizontal"
            action=""
            method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" >
              <input type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="{{$contact->id}}" >
              <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="{{$customer->id}}" >

                @include('form.customer')
                <div class="form-actions right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="next" formaction="{{url('p/contact/customer')}}">
                        Create
                    </button>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="next" value="update"formaction="{{url('p/customer/update')}}">
                        Update
                    </button>
                </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add if...else  condition like this.

```
@if(isset($customer->id) && $customer->id != null)
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="next" value="update"formaction="{{url('p/customer/update')}}">
                    Update
                </button>
@else
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="next" formaction="{{url('p/contact/customer')}}">
                    Create
                </button>
@endif
```